# QJsonObject insert corrupts utf8 string

Tags: json, qt, qt5.1

I have this code where tag.m_description is a QString containing Cyrillic characters: "Шщлщ"

```
QJsonObject json;
QJsonObject::iterator it = 
      json.insert("value", QJsonValue( tag.m_description );

qDebug(QJsonValue( tag.m_description ).toString());
qDebug((*it).toString());
```

This is the first and second output from the debug statements:

Шщлщ
⠄䤄㬄䤄

The first output is good. The second is not.

Any idea why QJsonObject::insert is corrupting my data?

Comment: Does (*it).isString() return true or false?

Comment: I just tried  (*it).isString(). It returned true.

Comment: Btw, the a call to setlocale(LC_ALL, "") shows the current locale is C

Comment: Are you using 5.1? Have you tried with the latest code, preferrably 5.3.0 beta?

Comment: I wouldn't use qDebug() for debugging encoding issues. What it prints will depend on your system locale, shell, etc. Better print something like toUtf8().toHex() and compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, looking at `QJsonObject` source code, that the string is stored as a unicode string instead of utf-8. It is stored internally in a utf-16 (two byte per character) array.